# SQL Query with Join and Count

Tags: sql, join, count

I don't have a lot of experience with complex queries and this one looks complex to me. Hope someone can help me.
I have two tables:

1. **[project]** with the following columns:

   ```
   [Id]
   [Name]
   [Street]
   [City]
   [State]
   [Country]
   [Postcode]
   [CreateDate]
   ```
2. **[stock]** with the following columns:

   ```
   [Id]
   [ProjectID]
   [Price]
   [Status]
   ```

Stock status can be **"Available"**, **"Reserved"** or **"Sold"**.

I need to select:

All projects created after '01-01-2016' and situated in a particular area (list of postcodes) and show the number of stock in each status for those projects.

So the result should be like this:

| Project Name | Street | City | State | Country | Created Date | Available | Reserved | Sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project Name 1 | Street1 | City1 | State1 | Country1 | 02-03-2021 | 153 | 25 | 76 |
| Project Name 2 | Street2 | City2 | State2 | Country1 | 05-03-2021 | 5 | 67 | 345 |

I don't have any problems with the WHERE part but have no idea how to use COUNT in this case.

Comment: JOIN, GROUP BY, use case expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several approaches to this problem. It can be done by case, subqueries. However, leveraging pivot function this can be done with very less code.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT name,street,city,state,country,postcode,createDate,status
FROM Project p JOIN Stock s ON p.Id=s.ProjectId
WHERE createDate >= '01-01-2016'
)
pivot 
(
COUNT(status) FOR status IN  ('Available','Reserved','Sold')
);
```

Comment: Hi rathourdevesh. Thank you so much for your help. This query returned the syntax error but I managed to get the data using PIVOT. Didn't know about it before. Thanks again!